# I am creating a new column, income to debt ratio, but output is coming in integer, instead of float

Tags: machine-learning, pandas

I need the income to debt ratio in float, when i tried manually it is coming infloat, but when i do in pandas, it is coming as integer. how can i take output in float numbers.

[image: This is I tried]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.